# Arch linux: automatic start of dhcpd on boot

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, dhcp, internet, dhcpcd

I am using arch linux and every time I boot y system I have to manually run:

```
sudo dhcpcd enp0s31f6
sudo dhcpcd wlan0
```

to have internet connection. How Can I make start these services automaticly after boot ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Try `sudo systemctl enable --now dhcpcd`.

Comment: Why aren't you using NM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for comments. The solution was combination of enabling systemd service:

```bsh
sudo systemctl enable --now dhcpcd
```

and uninstalling `Networkmanager` which I did not know I had installed and was causing nondeterministic behavior of my device.

```bsh
sudo pacman -Rs networkmanager
```

Thanks to every one who was trying to help.

and uninstalling network manager